# Setting creds in mysql_config_editor via Powershell, no prompt for password

Tags: mysql, powershell, mysql-5.6

I am having an issue with mysql in Powershell. In order to bypass the annoying "warning: using a password... blah blah" , I am attempting to set my creds via Powershell script.

So I have the following (abstracted):

```
$user=user
$password=secret

$setcreds= ."C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql_config_editor.exe" set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=$user --password;
```

The issue is that Powershell does not return to prompt me for a password. The command just hangs until I ctrl+C to return to a new line.

Any help getting past this would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does `mysql_config_editor.exe` allow you to specify a password on its command line?

Comment: In command line, it will not accept password as a parameter (using the command I posted in the OP), but it will prompt for password on the next line if you pass the --password switch. However, it is not getting to that prompt in Powershell. It just hangs on the command, acting like it is still executing.

Comment: And presumably you've read the documentation for this tool?